# NDEigensystem solutions depend on how many solutions I ask for?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

**Background**

I am using NDEigensystem to solve the following eigenvalue problem:

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} m&-i\partial_x \\ -i\partial_x & -m\end{matrix}\right)   \left( \begin{matrix} u_u(x) \\  u_d(x) \end{matrix} \right)=\lambda \left( \begin{matrix} u_u(x) \\  u_d(x) \end{matrix} \right),\qquad \text{with} \quad m = \begin{cases} m = -10, \, x \leq 0 \\ m = 10, \, x>0\end{cases} $$

I am specifically looking for solutions that vanish at $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.

**Code Implementetion**

My code is the following

```
mass1d[m1_, m2_, x_] := m2 UnitStep[x] - m1 UnitStep[-x]  (* mass function *)     

nSols = 10;(* number of solutions *)
{vals, sols} = NDEigensystem[{

(* Diff Equation *)
-I ud'[x] + mass1d[10, 10, x]*uu[x],
-I  uu'[x] -mass1d[10, 10, x]*ud[x],

(* Boundary conditions*)
DirichletCondition[uu[x] == 0, True],
DirichletCondition[ud[x] == 0, True]

}, {uu[x], ud[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, nSols](* SOLVER *) ;
```

**Problem/Question**

It is my understanding that NDEigensystem will return the solutions with the lowest (absolute value) eigenvalues. Hence, if I run my code asking for 5 solutions and then asking for 10 solutions, I would expect the 5 solutions in the first run also appear in the second run. This is not what happens. What I obtain is the following:
[image]

Aslo, when I ask for only 5 solutions I obtain the following warning that is not present when I ask for

```
Eigensystem::chnpdef: Warning: there is a possibility that the second matrix SparseArray[Automatic,<<2>>,{1,{{0,4,9,<<74>>,300,302},<<1>>},{0.08 +0. I,-0.01+0. I,0.02 +0. I,0.02 +0. I,-0.01+0. I,0.08 +0. I,<<290>>,0.16 +0. I,0.02 +0. I,0.02 +0. I,0.16 +0. I,0.02 +0. I,0.16 +0. I}}] in the first argument is not positive definite, which is necessary for the Arnoldi method to give accurate results.
```

Furhtermore, this problem has an analytical solution, which is $\lambda = 0$ and functions $u_u(x) \sim e^{-x}$ and $u_d(x) \sim e^{-x}$, which tells me asking for 10 solutions gives the correct answer.

Why do I get this warning only when I ask for 5 solution, but not when I look for 10?

**Complete code**
Above I write the way am finding the solutions, below is the complete code just to show there is no difference in how am running both cases:

```
*(* ----- 5 SOLUTIONS ------ *)
nSols = 5;(* number of solutions *)
{vals5, sols5} = NDEigensystem[{
   
   (* Diff Equation *)
   -I ud'[x] + mass1d[10, 10, x]*uu[x],
   -I  uu'[x] - mass1d[10, 10, x]*ud[x],
   
   (* Boundary conditions*)
   
   DirichletCondition[uu[x] == 0, True],
   DirichletCondition[ud[x] == 0, True]
   
   }, {uu[x], ud[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, nSols](* SOLVER *) ;
nSols = 10;(* number of solutions *)

(* ----- 10 SOLUTIONS -----*)
{vals10, sols10} = NDEigensystem[{
   
   (* Diff Equation *)
   -I ud'[x] + mass1d[10, 10, x]*uu[x],
   -I  uu'[x] - mass1d[10, 10, x]*ud[x],
   
   (* Boundary conditions*)
   DirichletCondition[uu[x] == 0, True],
   DirichletCondition[ud[x] == 0, True]
   
   }, {uu[x], ud[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, nSols](* SOLVER *) ;

(* PLOTING *) 
GraphicsGrid[
 {{
   BarChart[(ReIm /@ vals5)/Max[{m1, m2}], 
    ChartLegends -> {"Real Part", "Imaginary Part"}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Range[nSols], None}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Asking for 5 solutions"],
   Plot[Abs[sols5[[1]]]^2 /. {x -> x0} // Evaluate, {x0, -l, l}, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> "Asking for 5 solutions (1st result)", 
    PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(u\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(d\)]\)"}]
   },
  {
   BarChart[(ReIm /@ vals10)/Max[{m1, m2}], 
    ChartLegends -> {"Real Part", "Imaginary Part"}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Range[nSols], None}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Asking for 10 solutions"],
   Plot[Abs[sols10[[1]]]^2 /. {x -> x0} // Evaluate, {x0, -l, l}, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> "Asking for 10 solutions (1st result)", 
    PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(u\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(d\)]\)"}]
   }
  }
 , ImageSize -> Large]*
```

Comment: `mass1d` is nowhere defined.

Comment: added it, thanks!

Comment: I think you are fighting against numerical errors. Add the following to change the method used: `Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}`

Comment: @DanielHuber using the Direct Method does the trick. Any idea why the problem only arises when you ask for less solutions? Seems like asking for more solutions "fixes" the problem.

Comment: Don't you get a warning about this DE being convection dominated? What version and OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, I do get that warning as well.

Comment: I can only speculate.  "NDSolve" is a numerical routine and must take samples. It could be that sampling is different when you ask for more Eigenvalues. But write this question to wolfram at support@wolfram.com